# Rosdep: Adding dependencies that have to be compiled

Tags: ros, rosdep, rosmake, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have to integrate some external dependencies into my ROS packet, that are not available as debs but only source code on github. I thought that you have to declare in your manifest.xml , then create a rosdep.yaml file and put something like

```
someNameWhichIsNotOnThebase.yamlList: 
  ubuntu: 
mkdir -p ~/ros/ros-deps
    cd ~/ros/ros-deps
    wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/project/foo/tarball/master
    tar xpvf master
    cd master
    mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j4
sudo make install
```

(And I am not sure maybe search in CMakeLists.txt for this lib?)
But since it doesn't work, I would like to know how you are supposed to do this.
I would be very grateful for your help.

Regards,

Oier

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55899/rosdep:-adding-dependencies-that-have-to-be-compiled/) by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-21**:
What is your ROS distro? Are you using catkin? This is quite important for that question.

**Comment by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on 2013-02-21**:
I am using fuerte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep changed to rosdep2 in fuerte, so there is no more rosdep.yaml.

You have two possibilities here:

1. Use catkin for building the code. As the external code seems to be cmake, wrapping that should be really easy. However, I have no idea about the status of catkin in fuerte.
2. [Wrap the code](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Wrapping%20External%20Libraries) into a ROS package.

The second is probably closer to what you wanted to do originally.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2